# Find MySql query run time?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a simple way to find and display how long the last MySQL query took to execute? I'm thinking of a system function or similar in PHP. The best I've come up with so far is making two variables with microtime, where one is before the query and another after. Where the last one is substracted to the first one ($querytime = $after - $before).

The end result is meant to display what you find in PhpMyAdmin and similiar, i.e "Your query completed in xxxx.xx seconds".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start_time = microtime(true);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something");
$end_time = microtime(true);

$total_time = $end_time – $start_time;
//there isn't faster way
```

Comment: I have a very similar script in my php applications and sometimes my queries takes -0.232 (example, after multiplied by a thousand), and sometimes it takes 0.536 (example, after multiplied by a thousand). So I don't trust php's microtime, even though I still leave it there.

Comment: Okay, guess that's best/most accurate way for now. Thanks anyway :)